# how to display near hostel from my current location in android

Tags: android, geolocation

I want to display 5 kilometer around hostel from my current location ,In my server i am already saved hostel details and lat and lag values how to display to my current location .
what is the business logic for this any one help me

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do it is sending to the server your current location obtained in your android device and making a distance comparison with your latitude/longitude. [Here](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) you have a way to calculate this distance.

In any case, if you are using a normal SQL database you will find this operation slow, it is better to use databases optimised for distance and points operations called POI databases, such as OpenStreetMap.